# using ng-class on keyup function value

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I am trying to accomplish a simple valid toggle on the outcome of a keyup function. Basically, an input keyup action triggers a function. It does some stuff, then returns true or false. Upon this, the css class of span near the input should changes. Am I missing something in ng-class? I have searched for a similar topic but still couldn't overcome my problem.

html code:

```
        <div ng-repeat="drug in inputDrugs track by $index">
            <label>Type drug name</label><br/>
            <input ng-keyup="getRxcui(medValue, $index)" ng-model="medValue" placeholder="something like Advil" />
            <span class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-class="{'alert alert-success': getRxcui(medValue, $index)}">?</span>
        </div>
```

in controller.js:

```
$scope.getRxcui = function(medValue, index){
    var rxcui = '',
        url = 'blabla' + medValue;
    $http.get(url).
        success(function(data, status){
            try {
                // code here goes here and then..       
                return true
            }
            catch(err) {
                // If value is not correct:
                return false
            }
        }).
        error(function(data, status){
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            console.log('error receiving data: ' + status);
            console.error(data);
    });
}
```

I have managed to to so easily with jQuery, but the point for me is to keep angular code clean. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The return value is meaningless since it's all asynchronous. Whole different approach is needed.

Comment: so how can I accomplish it with angular, say ng-model? can I do something like ng-mode="mymodel" and then mymodel.css = 'alert...'?

Comment: Will post rough sample shortly, wanted to test it but out of time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you don't need to "override" the class you can have only one. Anyhow, the problem is that you are returning a value from a Promise, and it's meaningless.

Also, you have to associate the status of the request with the loop iterator so first change the markup to this:

```
<input ng-keyup="getRxcui(drug, medValue, $index)" ...
```

Now have this for the span:

```
<span role="alert" ng-class="{'alert alert-success': drug.rxcuiStatus == 'success', 
    'alert alert-danger': drug.rxcuiStatus == 'failure'}">
```

And finally in your function:

```
$scope.getRxcui = function(drug, medValue, index){
    var rxcui = '',
    url = 'blabla' + medValue;
    $http.get(url).
        success(function(data, status){
            try {
               // code here goes here and then..       
               drug.rxcuiStatus = 'success';
            }
            catch(err) {
                // If value is not correct:
                drug.rxcuiStatus = 'failure';
            }
        }).
        error(function(data, status){
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            console.log('error receiving data: ' + status);
            console.error(data);
            drug.rxcuiStatus = 'failure';
    });
};
```

Comment: cool, but how can I track each index in the ng-repeat div? (each span is for an input that the user can add another one).

Answer (score 1):

Your ng-class should look like this: `ng-class="{'alert alert-danger': !success ,'alert alert-success': success}">` . Here's why:

1) when you call `getRxcui(medValue, $index)` on the keyup event, simply modify the value of a scope variable: `$scope.success = true;` on success or false otherwise. 
You can then use that with ng-class : `ng-class="{'alert alert-success': success}">`.

2) You can't have a static "alert-danger" on the element. Because you can have only one alert type on that element, and if that's static, then the success class will be ignored (you'd get something like `<span class="alert alert-danger alert-success" role="alert">` - second modifier class gets ignored)

Comment: cool, but how can I track each index in the ng-repeat div? (each span is for an input that the user can add another one).  If I initiate $scope.success = ... than it's for everyone of the inputs!